# Why does Passport-jwt return unauthorized error

Tags: node.js, authentication, passport-jwt

I'm trying to make a very simple authentication scenario with passport-jwt. When I access a protected path, it keeps returning 'unauthorized'. I've tried almost everything suggested on similar threads but it doesn't work. All I want to do for now is have a call to 'authenticate' path in order the JWT token to be generated and then call the 'protected' path and allow access. For simplicity, I have all the code in server.js.

Here is the code:

```
const express = require("express");
const  passport  =  require('passport');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const  JWTStrategy  =  require('passport-jwt').Strategy;
const ExtractJwt = require('passport-jwt').ExtractJwt;
const secret = "s0m3$3Cret$h0lyC0d3&$";

const options = {
    jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken,
    secretOrKey: secret,
    algorithms: ['RS256']
  };

passport.use(new JWTStrategy(options, function(jwt_payload, done){
        return done(null, {id: 'FAKE_ID'});
    }
));

const app = new express();

app.get('/authenticate', (req, res, next) => {
    const token = jwt.sign({sub:'FAKE_ID'},secret,{expiresIn: 604800});
    res.status(200).json({ success: true, message: 'Logged in successfully!', token: 'Bearer ' + token});
})

app.get('/protected', passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }), (req, res, next) => {
    res.status(200).json({ success: true, msg: "You are successfully authenticated to this route!"});
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('App running at 3000')
})
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: you have `algorithms: ['RS256']`, but only a simple secret `const secret = "s0m3$3Cret$h0lyC0d3&$";`. That can't work. Either change to `HS256` (which will accept the secret, or create proper RSA Keys and use the private key for signing and the public key for verification. For the beginning, you better choose the first way.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried both but none works... Still getting unauthorized....